# DÚVIDA Sobre o uso de SELECT e Tabelas normalizadas

Tags: mysql, select, parâmetros, tabela-html, normalização

estou com uma dúvida quanto as vantagens de se ter tabelas normalizadas e quanto a suas formas de uso dentro de um SELECT.
Suponhamos as seguintes Tabelas:

```
 -------------- 
| tb_endereco  |
 --------------
| id           |
| rua          |
| numero       |
| bairro       |
| latitude     |
| longitude    |
|______________|

 -------------- 
|tb_solicitacao|
 --------------
| id           |
| id_origem    |
| id_destino   |
|______________|

 -------------- 
| tb_origem    |
 --------------
| id           |
| id_endereco  |
| responsavel  |
| observacoes  |
|______________|

 -------------- 
| tb_destino   |
 --------------
| id           |
| id_endereco  |
| responsavel  |
| observacoes  |
|______________|
```

Suponhamos, também que o cliente necessite de uma tabela com as seguintes informações referentes a Entrega numero 1:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rua_origem | lat_origem | long_origem | rua_destino | lat_destino | long_destino |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No caso pra que consiga retornar os dados como solicitado o SELECT deverá ser:

```
SELECT
(SELECT ende.rua FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_origem AS orig ON orig.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = orig.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'rua_origem',

(SELECT ende.latitude FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_origem AS orig ON orig.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = orig.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'lat_origem',

(SELECT ende.longitude FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_origem AS orig ON orig.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = orig.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'long_origem',

(SELECT ende.rua FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_destino AS dest ON dest.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = dest.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'rua_destino',

(SELECT ende.latitude FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_destino AS dest ON dest.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = dest.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'lat_destino',

(SELECT ende.longitude FROM tb_endereco AS ende
 INNER JOIN tb_destino AS dest ON dest.id_endereco = ende.id
 INNER JOIN tb_solicitacao AS entr ON entr.id_origem = dest.id
 WHERE entr.id = 1) AS 'long_destino'
FROM tb_solicitacao WHERE tb_solicitacao.id = 1
```

---

Desconheço uma outra forma de exibir esses dados com apenas 1 consulta no banco.

Sei que o uso de tabelas normalizadas vem de boas práticas e como forma de segurança para dificultar "SQL injection" no sitema.
Contudo o código além de ficar extenso ainda tem que se observar para que não haja erros quanto aos parâmetros do ID informados para que não haja desencontro das informações.

Minha dúvida é: Existe uma maneira mais prática de se obter os mesmos dados, sem tantos (SELECT) embutidos no código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O relacionamento que está tentando estabelecer não ficou claro. Se entendi bem acredito que se trata de um relacionamento de 1:1 entre as tabelas. Então poderia lançar um SQL dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
  end_origem.rua,
  end_origem.latitude,
  end_origem.longitude,
  end_destino.rua,
  end_destino.latitude,
  end_destino.longitude 
FROM 
  tb_solicitacao s INNER JOIN 
                               tb_origem  o ON  s.id_origem  = o.id 
                   INNER JOIN 
                               tb_destino d ON  s.id_destino =  d.id 
                   INNER JOIN 
                               tb_endereco end_origem  ON o.id_endereco = end_origem.id 
                   INNER JOIN 
                               tb_endereco end_destino ON d.id_endereco = end_destino.id 
WHERE 
      s.id = 1;
```

Esse simples exemplo relaciona a tabela solicitações com as tabelas de origem e destino e seus devidos endereços. Repare o uso do **INNER JOIN**, a consulta diz que vocês deseja resgatar todos os registros que contiverem na tabela solicitação e **obrigatoriamente (INNER JOIN)** tiverem registros que se relacionam pelo atributo **id_origem e id_destino** em suas tabelas respectivas, bem como também as tabelas **tb_origem e tb_destino** devem obrigatoriamente se relacionar com a tabela **tb_endereco**  pelo atributo **id_endereço**.

**INNER JOIN** só ira resgatar se contiver registros em todas as tabelas do relacionamento;

> Para existir uma solicitação, obrigatoriamente deve existir uma
>   origem e um destino bem como seus endereços respectivos.

Digamos que exista uma nova tabela que se relacione podendo ou não conter registros relacionados, nesse caso se lançaria o uso do **LEFT JOIN**.

Eu montei esse exemplo com base em sua querie acima, mas não fiz qualquer modelagem no banco e nem teste. Adapte a seu gosto! O conceito para relacionar usando estruturas normalizadas é esse, não aconselho seguir outro caminho por mais que pareça fácil, lá na frente vai gerar sérios problemas sobre expansão e manutenção.

Abraços.

Comment: Olá @RafaelSalomão - Realmente, a forma que apresentou é bem mais simples, e não tinha pensado nessa forma: instanciando 2 vezes a mesma tabela com variáveis diferentes, de fato não pensei!... Por mais que ainda ache que quanto mais complexo o banco ele sempre será mais trabalhoso e com linhas extensas de código, tenho que concordar que: >seguir outro caminho por mais que pareça fácil, lá na frente vai gerar sérios problemas sobre expansão e manutenção.